# Github.com issues with TFS source control, is it possible?

Tags: github, tfs

Is it possible to use Github for the issues, TFS for source control, and reference the github issue ids on the TFS checkins?

We use TFS and there's no plan to switch to Git in the near future.
The product owner is out of our network and we can't allow them VPN access so they can't see the issues on TFS.

Comment: Perhaps a migration to VS Team Services is in order?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We will migrate to VS TS soon and as I see it has all functionality I needed from github :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not supported to add issues in Github when check in code at TFS. It could only add workitems in TFS.

If they couldn't see those workitem, you could [export those workitems from TFS to Excel](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel) and send to them. Or like Daniel said in the comment, you could use VSTS instead of using TFS.